# Setting batch file variable to Last Day of previous month

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am attempting to get the last day of the previous month and set a variable to that in a batch file.

For example if today's date is 2016-10-18 I want my variable set to 2016-09-30

Comment: [possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37171139/2152082)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to write something in a different language to echo the date to stdout. Any language will do, but here's an implementation in VBS

```
' Save this as LastDayOfLastMonth.vbs
Function Pad(Value, PadCharacter, Length)
    Pad = Right(String(Length,PadCharacter) & Value, Length)
End Function

Dim Today
Today = Date
FirstOfMonth = DateSerial(Year(Today), Month(Today), 1)
WScript.Echo FirstOfMonth
LastOfPreviousMonth = DateAdd("d", -1, FirstOfMonth)
WScript.Echo Pad(Year(LastOfPreviousMonth), "0", 4) & "-" & _
 Pad(Month(LastOfPreviousMonth), "0", 2) & "-" & _ 
 Pad(Day(LastOfPreviousMonth), "0", 2)
```

then call it from your batch file:

```
@echo off
FOR /F %%i IN ('cscript "%~dp0LastDayOfLastMonth.vbs" //Nologo') do SET MYDATE=%%i
echo %MYDATE%
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    call :getPreviousMonthLastDate lastDay
    echo %lastDay%

    exit /b 

:getPreviousMonthLastDate returnVar
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    set "y=" & for /f "tokens=1-2 delims=/" %%a in ('
        robocopy "|" . /njh
    ') do if not defined y set /a "y=%%a", "m=1%%b-100"
    if %m% equ 1 ( set /a "y-=1" , "m=12", "d=31" ) else ( 
        set /a "m-=1", "d=30+((m+m/8) %% 2)", "m+=100" 
        if %m% equ 3 set /a "d=d-2+!(y%%4)-!(y%%100)+!(y%%400)"
    )
    endlocal & set "%~1=%y%-%m:~-2%-%d:~-2%" & exit /b
```

Arithmetic apart, the code uses `robocopy` command to generate an error and retrieve the current date in a locale independent way. You can replace it with any other method available and keep the rest of the calcs, but `y` must contain the year in `yyyy` format and `m` must contain the month number without left zero padding.